# Handling ORA error in Unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to execute a script which actually runs a SQL and returns the value , write to to a CSV file and send it.

/data/oracle/product/10.2.0.4/bin/sqlplus -s user_name/password@DBName @/export/home/script/abc.sql

I want to capture the error whenever there is any error while running the SQL part but it always hangs.

I tried putting "(($?)) && ((ERRORS += 1))" after above statement but it never reaches to that line.

I want to capture the error code in a variable ERROR and exit with the error code.

Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

you can put it under TRY-Catch block. refer this [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to capture the error via shell script you have to remove you error handling from your SQL and set the script to rollback and return the error:

WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 9 ROLLBACK;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE ROLLBACK;